# Как реализовать чат?

Tags: java, сокет

Добрый день. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Можно ли с помощью сокетов реализовать передачу сообщения. Т.е что-бы писать и обмениваться сообщениями.

И с помощью чего это сделать?

Сериализация подойдет?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- [Java TCP Sockets and Swing Tutorial](http://www.ashishmyles.com/tutorials/tcpchat/index.html)
- [The Chat Application](http://oreilly.com/catalog/javmesser/chapter/ch02.html#89010)
- [Simple Chat Example](http://xcf.sourceforge.net/docs/xcf/jxcf/simpleChatExample.html)

Ключевые слова для поиска: java, chat, example, sample.

Comment: Абсолютно правильный совет. Пример по сокетам с сановского сайта реализует, почти, именно то, что вам нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, с помощью [RMI](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RMI)

Comment: RMI для этого слишком тяжеловесна и сложна. Простой чат сделать на сокетах проще пареной репы без всякого RMI.